# MVC Code First Publish

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I have created a code first MVC application and I am having issues with a certain part of the publish.

I am getting the error message of

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)
>
> SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:
>
> The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance
>   using a database location within the application's App_Data directory

Now, my connection string is pointing to the correct server, and everything about the connection string is fine. I am not using a local db inside the `App_Data` folder.

I am at an utter stand still.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said the connection string is fine, but you should double check. With the credentials and server path on your connection string can you connect by sql management for example ? If yes, your problem probably is database permission